# Excel VBA conditional formatting based on next cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do some conditional formatting in Excel for the font size but seeing as it can't be done from the format menu, it needs to be done with VBA.

I have a range B6 to however many rows and I want to look at the cell next to it and see if it's blank (column C).  If it is then format the cell to Bold and 11pt.  If it's not blank then it needs to be normal and 9pt.

My code at the minute only makes the last row Bold and 11pt and the rest of the column, even if column C is empty will be normal 9pt.

What is going wrong?  BTW I'm using Excel 2003

```
Dim c As Range, rng
Dim LASTROW As Long

LASTROW = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("B6:B" & LASTROW)
For Each c In rng
    If Len(c.Offset(1, 0)) = 0 Then
        c.Font.Bold = True
        c.Font.Size = 11
    Else
        c.Font.Bold = False
        c.Font.Size = 9
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: You *can* do this with conditional formatting, using a formula

Comment: Using Excel 2003 so the option to change font size is greyed out

Comment: It's not available in XL 2007/10 either.  You do have to use VBA to change the font size.

Comment: @DougGlancy: Very true for `font size` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Offset parameters are backwards.  You are checking the cell below the current one.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Here's how]

Note the trick is to use a single rule, coded for the top-left cell

Comment: You can't use conditional formatting to change font size in any version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need a macro - you can do it using a formula in Conditional Formatting.

Say you wanted to highlight the adjacent cell in column B red when the cell in column C had a value of "Red":

```
=IF(C6="Red",TRUE,FALSE)
```

then just fill down with the fill handle as usual.

Rule editor (2007):

[image]

Comment: You can't use conditional formatting to change font size in any version of Excel.

Comment: -1 for using an If statement.  The "conditional" in conditional formatting means you just use something like `"=C6="Red"`.

Comment: @DougGlancy Fair enough, I just think it reads more clearly this way.