# Excel VBA use value from another cell as formula for conditional formating

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sorry for such a stupid question, I'm not a programer myself and I've been pieceing togeter a macro from bits I found over the internet and I'm left with just a coupe of lines of code I simply cannot get the answer to.

I've done everything I want the macro to do, except the conditional formating bit. The thing is I want it to apply format (green cells) to cells greater than whatever the value of the cell 4 rows above the one I'm currently in, and then apply a different format (red cells) to cells with lower values than whatever the value of the same cell(4 rows above), but this time I need the value to be negative.

The problem is that I dont know how to tell the macro to look for the value of the cell 4 rows above the one I'm standing in, and, once done that, how to tell the macro to change the sign of the cell (multipling by -1)

here is the piece of code i've troubles with.

```
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
        Formula1:
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16752384
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13561798
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
        Formula1:
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

As you can see, i've left the Formula1: empty, that's where I'd like to tell the macro to look for the value four cells above the one I'm in

The next Formula1: that's empty needs to look for the value of the cell four cells above and then multyply by -1 or whatever it takes to change the value to negative.

I hope that you can help me out here.
(sorry for the sloppy english and poor spelling, not my native languaje)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA conditional formatting based on next cell value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802281/excel-vba-conditional-formatting-based-on-next-cell-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need to use format conditioning. 
Anyway, below is the working code to demonstrate how this can be done. Please note that multiplying by (-1) is a dangerous thing. Imagine what would happen if you run the macro more than once?

```
Option Explicit
Sub conditional_formatting1()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.Selection
Dim c As Range

For Each c In rng.Cells
    c.FormatConditions.Delete

    If c.Value < c.Offset(-4).Value Then

        'setting color to red
        c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        'multipyling -1
        c.Value = c.Value * (-1)

    Else

        With c


            .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & c.Address & ">" & c.Offset(-4)
            'implementatio of what you wanted to do below is commented.
            'uncomment it if you want to use it or continue using what I have done below

'            With .FormatConditions(1).Font
'                .Color = -16383844
'                .TintAndShade = 0
'            End With
'            With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
'                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
'                .Color = 13551615
'                .TintAndShade = 0
'            End With

            'changing cell color to green
            c.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End With

    End If
Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to tweak you code a little bit and got it to work with the whole macro, thanks again for your time

Comment: mark as answer, please or post further info. Thanks